# Could not parse the remainder. Jinja ternary

Tags: python, jinja2

What is wrong in my jinga logic?

```
 <a href="?page={{ 'Some True data' if True else 'Some else data' }}" class="page-link"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a>
```

This my error

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' if True else 'Some else data'' from ''Some true data' if True else 'Some else data''
```

Here doc [link](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#if-expression).
Here template from doc:

```
<do something> if <something is true> else <do something else>
```

Comment: `true` <> `True`. Booleans are uppercase in `Python`.

Comment: @Jan Ok, you're right. But result is the same.

Comment: can you please post the actual code, not the logic? Because the error is talking about misused quotations

Comment: Thanks, I`m new in Python. I use django templates, but not jinja2 templates

Answer (score 0):

Connect to project jinja2 templates

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {'environment': 'folivora.jinja2.environment', },
},
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/test'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

with jinja2.py file